# Node.JS express server creation methods difference

Tags: node.js, express

I have recently inherited a project of a Node.JS and Express based API, and I have noticed express server creation is as such (simplified version):

```
// http is required.
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Note http is used to create server, and app is used as param:
http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function (request, response) {

    console.log('listening on port 3000');

});
```

Everything works as expected of course.
I have been trying to figure out what exactly is happening behind the scenes here, mostly in comparison to the method in Express API, which shows:

```
// http is not required.
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Note Express is used to create the server:
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

    console.log('listening on port 3000');

})
```

Note the difference in server creation using http, and using Express directly.

Is there any benefit in using a specific one of the two method? What is the actual difference between the two?
Micro-optimization-wise, is it preferred to avoid requiring 'http', which is probably required by express anyway?

Thanks from ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are more or less functionally equivalent, in the second example the `express` constructor returns a new object which effectively wraps up the `http.createServer` call internally (i.e. when you call [app.listen](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L557)).

If you are going to use express then you should use it's recommended APIs, the first approach is considered outdated.